# Fixed number conversion with different precision

Tags: haskell, numbers

I'm new to Haskell, and I can't figure out how to convert a **NominalDiffTimeSource** (from the package [time](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.7/docs/Data-Time-Clock.html#t:NominalDiffTime), which has a precision of `10^-12`) to a **Micro** (from the [base](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Data-Fixed.html#t:Micro) package, which has a precision of `10^-6`).

Comment: [`realToFrac`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:realToFrac)?

Comment: I searched for a while, but I didn't find this... It fits perfectly my needs, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but it feels like this deserves a longer answer than the one in the comments...

The `NominalDiffTime` type has instances for various numeric typeclasses (`Num`, `Fractional`, etc.) which allow it to be treated as a plain numeric type in seconds.  This allows you to write things like:

```
halfSecondLater :: NominalDiffTime -> NominalDiffTime
halfSecondLater x = x + 0.5
```

Similarly, `Micro` is just a type alias for `Fixed E6` which is a fixed precision numeric type with an appropriate set of numeric typeclasses.

So, converting a `NominalDiffTime` type (which is a numeric type in seconds) to a `Micro` (which is a numeric type in some unspecified unit that could be seconds) is not much different than converting a `Double` to a `Float`.

The general conversion function between real, but non-integer, numeric types is the function `realToFrac`, which no one can ever remember or find, because it's named for the typeclasses it converts between (since `Real` implements `toRational` while `Fractional` implements `fromRational`) instead of what it's actually used for.

So, you could use `realToFrac` directly, or write a specialization:

```
nominalToMicro :: NominalDiffTime -> Micro
nominalToMicro = realToFrac
```